# AFNetworking umlauts

Tags: encoding, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to communicate with my JSON API. Everything ist fine except of sending requests with german umlauts (i.e. ä ö ü ß).

I am using a shared instance

```
+(LFMessaging*)shared
{
    static LFMessaging *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });    
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

to send data i use a subclass of AFHTTPClient with this method:

```
[parameters setValue:cmd forKey:@"cmd"];
NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
[self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@%@", _domain, _target]
                          parameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
           constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
               //TODO: attach file if needed
           }];

AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
operation.JSONReadingOptions = NSJSONReadingMutableContainers;

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
...
```

just when a parameter with a german umlaut ist passed the api seems to break. the server does not receive the correct string.

if the server sends umlauts in a json result everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.stringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
```

solved the problem